# I have to find the youngest creation date of a document from folders and subfolders in oracle tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a folders table with folder_id and parent_id to make a hierarchy.
I have a document table with a folder_ id to link documents to folders.
From there, nothing complicated.

From a query I can show the folders ordered by the oldest creation date:

```
select level lvl,   
    t.fld_id folder_id,
    lpad(' ',(level -1)*10) || t.folder_name folder_name,
    to_char(t.created, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS') created
from
(select y.folder_id fld_id, y.name folder_name, y.parent_id prt_id, y.created
 from   folders y   
 order by y.created asc
) t
connect by prior t.fld_id = t.prt_id
start with t.fld_id = <base folder_id>
```

What comes now complicated, for me, is that I have to show near the folder creation date, the creation date of the youngest document from the folder and the subfolder.

For example, I have:

```
folder 1
    folder 10
        doc creation (1/1/2012)
        doc creation (1/10/2012)
    folder 11
        doc creation (1/2/2012)
        folder 110
            doc creation (1/1/2013)
```

In this I should see near folder 1, folder 11 and folder 110, the doc creation date 1/1/2013 as it is the youngest document in the whole hierarchy. And near folder 10, I should see 1/10/2012. I don't have to see the document, only the youngest creation date near the folder name.

Hope you understand :)

Should an expert be able to show me how to proceed this ?
Thank you in advance,
Michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look on this complete example if this is you want to see:

```
CREATE TABLE FOLDERS(FOLDER_ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(25)
     , PARENT_ID NUMBER, CREATED DATE);
CREATE TABLE FILES(FOLDER_ID NUMBER, FILE_ID NUMBER, CREATED DATE);

INSERT INTO folders VALUES (1, 'root', NULL, DATE '2013-01-11');
INSERT INTO folders VALUES (2, '10',      1, DATE '2013-03-12');
INSERT INTO folders VALUES (3, '11',      1, DATE '2013-05-13');
INSERT INTO folders VALUES (4, '12',      1, DATE '2013-02-14');
INSERT INTO folders VALUES (5, '110',     3, DATE '2013-01-15');

INSERT INTO files VALUES (1, 1, DATE '2013-03-01');
INSERT INTO files VALUES (2, 2, DATE '2013-04-01');
INSERT INTO files VALUES (2, 3, DATE '2013-03-01');
INSERT INTO files VALUES (3, 4, DATE '2013-04-01');
INSERT INTO files VALUES (3, 5, DATE '2013-05-01');
INSERT INTO files VALUES (5, 6, DATE '2013-01-10');
```

If you want to sort levels you can use: `ORDER SIBLINGS BY DATE_YOU_WANT_TO_COMPARE`
Look on this select:

```
SELECT LEVEL LVL
     , T.FLD_ID FOLDER_ID
     , LPAD( ' ', (LEVEL - 1) * 5) || 'FOLDER ' || T.FOLDER_NAME FOLDER_NAME
     , TO_CHAR( T.CREATED, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS') CREATED
     , TO_CHAR( T.CREATED_COMBINE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS') CREATED_COMBINE
FROM (  SELECT Y.FOLDER_ID FLD_ID
            , Y.NAME FOLDER_NAME
            , Y.PARENT_ID PRT_ID
            , Y.CREATED
            , NVL(X.MIN_DOC_CREATED, Y.CREATED) CREATED_COMBINE
         FROM FOLDERS Y
            , (  SELECT MIN(F.CREATED) MIN_DOC_CREATED
                      , F.FOLDER_ID
                   FROM FILES F
               GROUP BY F.FOLDER_ID) X
              -- use left join for folders without files
        WHERE Y.FOLDER_ID = X.FOLDER_ID(+)
     ORDER BY Y.CREATED ASC) T
CONNECT BY PRIOR T.FLD_ID = T.PRT_ID
START WITH T.PRT_ID IS NULL
ORDER SIBLINGS BY CREATED_COMBINE
```

I connect folders to `MIN` of date from files and then join it to folders with left join (for folders without files), then you can use this `MIN` from files or date of creation for folder if no files inside.

**For sorting of result look on last condition.**

*And here is the result*
*(Folder name, folder created date, combine created date from min files inside folder)*

**ASC** sorting (in example SELECT above):

```
FOLDER root             11/01/2013  01/03/2013
     FOLDER 10          12/03/2013  01/03/2013
     FOLDER 11          13/05/2013  01/04/2013
          FOLDER 110    15/01/2013  10/01/2013
     FOLDER 12          14/02/2013  14/02/2013
```

**DESC** sorting (add DESC after last: `ORDER SIBLINGS BY CREATED_COMBINE DESC`):

```
FOLDER root             11/01/2013  01/03/2013
     FOLDER 12          14/02/2013  14/02/2013
     FOLDER 11          13/05/2013  01/04/2013
          FOLDER 110    15/01/2013  10/01/2013
     FOLDER 10          12/03/2013  01/03/2013
```

If you need **minimum value from all childs**, you can create select like this:

```
WITH PATH_LIST AS (
    SELECT LEVEL LVL
         , T.FLD_ID FOLDER_ID
         , LPAD( ' ', (LEVEL - 1) * 5) || 'FOLDER ' || T.FOLDER_NAME FOLDER_NAME
         , CREATED
         , CREATED_COMBINE
         , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( TO_CHAR(FLD_ID), '/') PATH
      FROM (SELECT Y.FOLDER_ID FLD_ID
                 , Y.NAME FOLDER_NAME
                 , Y.PARENT_ID PRT_ID
                 , Y.CREATED
                 , NVL(X.MIN_DOC_CREATED, Y.CREATED) CREATED_COMBINE
              FROM FOLDERS Y
                 , (SELECT MIN(F.CREATED) MIN_DOC_CREATED
                         , F.FOLDER_ID
                      FROM FILES F
                  GROUP BY F.FOLDER_ID) X
           WHERE Y.FOLDER_ID = X.FOLDER_ID(+)
        ORDER BY Y.CREATED ASC) T
    CONNECT BY PRIOR T.FLD_ID = T.PRT_ID
    START WITH T.PRT_ID IS NULL
    ORDER SIBLINGS BY CREATED_COMBINE)
SELECT A.FOLDER_NAME
     , A.PATH
     , A.LVL "LEVEL"
     , (SELECT MIN(C.CREATED_COMBINE)
          FROM PATH_LIST C
         WHERE C.PATH LIKE A.PATH || '%')
      MINIMUM_FROM_CHILDS
 FROM PATH_LIST A
GROUP BY A.FOLDER_NAME
       , A.PATH
       , A.LVL
ORDER BY 4, 3
```

Result from this select will be:
*(Structure: `folder_name`, `path`, `level`, `minimum_from_childs`)*

```
FOLDER root             /1      1   2013-01-10
     FOLDER 11          /1/3    2   2013-01-10
          FOLDER 110    /1/3/5  3   2013-01-10
     FOLDER 12          /1/4    2   2013-02-14
     FOLDER 10          /1/2    2   2013-03-01
```

As you can see `folder root` get date from sub-`folder 110`.

Comment: HI Atiris, Thank you for the answer. It is really better, but not yet what i'm looking for :)

Comment: In your example, if this is possible, I would like to have this: doc date for folder root, 1/4/2013, because this is the youngest doc in subfolder 10 and the parent should take the date of the youngest doc from itself or from the subfolders. Folder 12, no date because there are no documents, nor subfolders with docs. Folder 10, 1/4/2012, the youngest from itself. Folder 11, 1/2/2013, the youngest doc from itself too, or should it be a youngest doc in a subfolder, the date from this one...

Comment: I extended my example to meet your requirements. Look on it now (changes are also in input data, so drop tables folders and files and try create it and fill again) - it is part _If you need minimum value from all childs, you can create select like this_

Comment: Hi Atiris, this is really what I needed (I 've changed a lot of things to adapt it to my needs, added the folder creation date desc, turn the min doc creation into max doc creation... But you made the biggest part of the query, thank of this, and greeting from Belgium :)